# putting hyperlinks in TextViews - but not knowing the address in advance

Tags: android, hyperlink

I need to localize an Android app in many languages. But the text also contains a local web link like `www.theLink.com, www.LinkForOtherLanguage1.it, www.yetAnotherLinkForOtherLanguage2.fr`,... you get the idea :)

I know this way to linkify...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("www.theLink.com");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, "http://");
```

But here I need to know the addresses and put them in the code. Is there any way without changing the code for each language?

Many thanks

Comment: Link is static value or dynamic value?

Comment: the link is static, but different for each language

Comment: You need to use string.xml to put values or else need Dynamic values.. Okay how many values will be there?

Comment: I just thought of this too - I guess that's the most feasible solution - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the links in a string array and get them by position according to what language it is

Comment: but if I don't know the links in advance? I need a way to detect ANY link written like www.xxx.yyy WITHOUT knowing beforehand...

Comment: Thank you, I think I will do something simial